# Plain HTML5 audio player : duration and start

Tags: javascript, html, audio

It's very simple to design an audio player with HTML5 :

```html
 <audio controls>
  <source src="http://picosong.com/cdn/27590d7ce366627ec0d20d06ec2bbe1c.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I would like to set a starting point (ex: 1'26") and a duration (ex: 10 seconds), i.e. the player shouldn't display the whole audio file, but only these 10 seconds.

**How to do set start point and duration with HTML5's `<audio>` with plain HTML5 or HTML5+JS?** (i.e. no big third party JS library)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the playback range in audio files url. 
Like this #t=[starttime][,endtime]

[mdn article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video)

Example:

```html
<audio controls>
  <source src="http://picosong.com/cdn/27590d7ce366627ec0d20d06ec2bbe1c.mp3#t=120,130" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it will still display the whole song (length : 4'08") instead of 10 seconds duration when I use `#t=120,130` : http://gget.it/w89cyf9v/1.jpg  (but ok the starting point is set properly.  the problem is that you cannot go back easily to the starting point if you want to relisten again)